# Sabre BFMv1 (REST)

Tags: sabre

is there away to compute for the elapsed time in an itinerary wherein the flight crosses the international dateline? ex LAX-MNL

LAX deptdate 2020/04/15 23:10:00 +08:00

MNL arrivaldate 2020/04/15 21:45:00-07:00

new version of BFM Rest doesn't have elapsed time in the response.
any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the latest specs using the following link:- https://developer.sabre.com/sites/default/files/2020-04/BargainFinderMax_NDC_Guide_2020.pdf

Elapsed time has been added in the API response as of 4Q 2019.

In addition, the Flight Details (VerifyFlightDetailsLLSRQ) API can be used to verify details about a specific flight number on a specific date. Using this API, you can:
•   Verify flight details for a range of lines in a Get Air Availability response
•   Verify flight details for multiple, nonconsecutive lines in a Get Air Availability response

Flight details include but are not limited to items such as origin, destination, flight number, departure date and time, arrival date and time, elapsed time and equipment type.

You can refer to the following link for request and response formats:- https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/book/Flight_Details